# jq: How do I assign a jq output to a variable?

Tags: json, bash, if-statement, jq

I'm new to jq and struggling to obtain a json value and use it in a bash IF statement.

```json
{
    "animal": "elephant",
    "colour": "red"
}
```

```bash
VAR=$( jq '.animal' animal.json )
echo "$VAR"

if [[ "$VAR" == "elephant" ]]; then
      echo "this is an elephant"
else
      echo "failed"
fi
```

When I run the script the comparison fails

What can change to make the script work?

Answer (score 4):

`jq` outputs `"elephant"`, note the `"`

Add `-r` to the `jq` command so the quotes are removed (raw-mode)

---

Then the output will match the string `elephant`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

VAR="$(jq -r '.animal' animal.json)"
echo "$VAR"

if [[ "$VAR" == "elephant" ]]; then
      echo "this is an elephant"
else
      echo "failed"
fi
```